# python django pass javascript object from view

Tags: javascript, python, django, object, json.net

With python dictionary and json.dumps I've been able to do things like:

```
json.dumps({'title': 'string','b': 2, 'c': None})
```

which will result in the string:

```
'{"a": "string", "b": 2, "c": null}'
```

then all I had to do is pass it to javascript code (with |safe filter) and it will interpret it as json.

but now I need to create in my django view something that will result in:

```
{title: "string", func: $.someFunc}
```

notice, there aren't quotes on the "title" key and I use more complicated values like functions.

Specifically, I'm using [Jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com) to create charts. But I need to configure my charts' properties based on data that I have on the server (e.g. number of axes, type of axis, and other properties).
So my attempt is to create these javascript objects in the django view.

[Example](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php) for a jqplot charts. I need to create the plotOptions on the server.

Comment: Why don't you create the javascript function in a javascript file and include it?

Comment: Quotes on title key do not matter. You can put them or not put them. However, beware of using json.dumps  to pass data to your html, use https://github.com/fusionbox/django-argonauts or similar

Comment: What I mean is, you are vulnerable to attacks if you use |safe with json.dumps.

Comment: @schillingt I don't understand. please suggest me a way how can I configure my chart from django view. I pull the data for the chart from the database, than I need to decide some properties about the chart, based on the data - number of axis, labels etc.s

Comment: @ustun the quotes on the title are just an example. What I need is a way to create the options for my chart in django view, since the options are based on data that I only have in the view.

Comment: I think you need to make clear what you are trying to do. as it is, it is hard to understand what the issue is. you need to pass the python data into the html in a script tag, and pass that to your js, at what point are you stuck at?

Comment: I can easily pass the data for my chart, which is basically array of [x,y] points. What I need is to pass to the chart other options from my view, like the number of axes and others. See here how you configure a jqplot chart: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php. As you can see, the chart accept properties like axes: {..}  , axesDefaults : {..} . those I want to create in my view.